# Limited to write only a-z in angular

Tags: angularjs

I want to let user to write just english character not number or any languages .
here is my fiddle : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/49pg3/143/) but it's not working .

```
app.directive('validcharEn', function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            if (!ngModelCtrl) {
                return;
            }

            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (val) {
                if (angular.isUndefined(val)) {
                    var val = '';
                }
                var clean = val.replace(/[^a-z]/g, '');
                var decimalCheck = clean.split('.');
                if (!angular.isUndefined(decimalCheck[1])) {
                    decimalCheck[1] = decimalCheck[1].slice(0, 2);
                    clean = decimalCheck[0] + '.' + decimalCheck[1];
                }

                if (val !== clean) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
                    ngModelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return clean;
            });

            element.bind('keypress', function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode === 10) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49pg3/147/) , clean and simplest way to do it .

```
app.directive('validEn', function() {
  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      if(!ngModelCtrl) {
        return; 
      }

      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(val) {
        var clean = val.replace( /[^a-z]+/g, '');
        if (val !== clean) {
          ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
          ngModelCtrl.$render();
        }
        return clean;
      });

      element.bind('keypress', function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode === 32) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="employee.age" valid-en />
```

**Update**
or maybe for email input :

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49pg3/148/)**

```
var clean = val.replace( /[^0-9+.+a-z+@]+/g, '');
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [ng-pattern-restrict](http://alphagit.github.io/ng-pattern-restrict/) directive:

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern-restrict="^[a-z]*$" />
```

Here'a an example: http://jsfiddle.net/upcvoa4L/

Comment: @Soheil Sorry, fixed the link.

Comment: many thanks , i've seen it , but isn't too much code for that purpose?

Comment: @Soheil It seems tested and flexible. You can choose to go on with your own implementation but I don't think it's a complicated piece of code.